# Using JAR parameters in JNLP file

Tags: java, xml, command-line-arguments, jnlp, java-web-start

I have a question how to run JAR files with the parameters using a JNLP protocol . For example, to properly run the selenium-server-standalone-2.21.0.jar package I call it as:

```
selenium-server-standalone-2.21.0.jar -timeout 60000 -trustAllSSLCertificates -port 5555
```

When I add these parameters as:

```
<jar href="/selenium-server-standalone-2.21.0.jar -timeout 60000 -trustAllSSLCertificates -port 5555"/>
```

I'm getting error - no such file found. I guess that these parameters are treated as part of the file name and for this reason I got this error. Where can I place the parameters for the call JAR package in XML below.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://test.com/">
<information>
  <title>Selenium-Server-Standalone-2.21.0</title>
  <vendor>ESKY Testers Toolkit</vendor>
  <homepage href="http://www.esky.pl/"/>
  <description>starts selenium server on client machine</description>
</information>
<security>
  <all-permissions/>
</security>
<resources>
  <j2se version="1.4+"/>
  <jar href="/selenium-server-standalone-2.21.0.jar"/>
</resources>
<application-desc main-class="org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer"/>
</jnlp>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `arg` elements as children of the `application-desc` element.  E.G.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://test.com/">
<information>
  <title>Selenium-Server-Standalone-2.21.0</title>
  <vendor>ESKY Testers Toolkit</vendor>
  <homepage href="http://www.esky.pl/"/>
  <description>starts selenium server on client machine</description>
</information>
<security>
  <all-permissions/>
</security>
<resources>
  <j2se version="1.4+"/>
  <!-- size.  The downloadable size of the JAR file in bytes. -->
  <jar href="/selenium-server-standalone-2.21.0.jar" size="21247" />
</resources>
<application-desc main-class="org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer">
    <argument>-timeout</argument>
    <argument>60000</argument>
    <!-- etc... -->
</application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

---

Former comments (now deleted).

- Uninstall the app. before testing the new JNLP. The launch files can be very update resistant. In fact, when changing the JNLP - I'd generally change the cache location (via the Java Control Panel) to test the new launch file.
- JNLP.  Check the (well-formedness and) validity (amongst other things) of the launch file using [JaNaLA](http://pscode.org/janela/). Correct any errors in pink/red before proceeding to another test.

Comment: @andrew-thomson: Your solution looks good in theory (there are no errors on startup) but... for example, `-port 5555` should switch server port to 5555 - but it still works on the default port 4444. I found another solution `<arg line="port -5555" />` but result is exactly the same - server doesn't switched on port 5555.

Comment: I removed application from Java Cache Viewer. I do this every time I test another solution. Is there a more effective method to remove application like `uninstall`?

Comment: I try to run `javaws -uninstall` to remove all applications - still nothing

Comment: I removed all cache for javaws and try again, but still nothing. My JNLP is available at http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4105635/selenium.jnlp. I run this as `javaws http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4105635/selenium.jnlp`. After executing application server should listening on port 5555, but currently service is running on port 4444 (default). I checked it on windows `netstat -a` and linux `lsof -i :5555`

Comment: Ok, I'll fix it. In case of problems, I'll get back in this thread soon. BTW nice tool

Comment: *"BTW nice tool"*  (On behalf of Walter Laan & myself) You're welcome.  :)

Comment: I'll finally solve the problem (of cource with help of You, Walter and JaNaLa ;) ). The correct name of `application-name` children is `<argument> </argument>`. For example `<argument>-port</argument> <argument>5555<argument>`.

Comment: @andrew-thomas: If I may ask one more question: `Downloads can be optimized by specyfying size for <jar_name>`. Could you give me example how to use it (based on my JNLP)?

Comment: Thanks Andrew. It (`size`) was so simple :) Have a nice day (and night for me) and thanks for help

Comment: A question inside the jar, how obtain the params?  I would like to use the params inside my jar program-

Comment: @FernandoPie You'd better ask your own question (in a separate question thread). Please make it more clear than the one asked in the comment above.